# unity + vuforia require sdk android 5

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, vuforia

I am using unity 5.1.1 and vuforia v5.0.5 , documents say it works with android 4.0.3, but while building it asks for android platform 5 minimum (API 21)

Is there a way to limit it to jelly beans?

The project I am trying to build is a new vuforia project , I havn't changed a thing

I defined the project to support android 4.2, though it asks for API 21 even when configured to minimum support gingerbread

Comment: Check that the manifest gets the proper level API. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html